# UITableCell height doesn't size correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I've created a `xib` for a `UITableViewCell` which will have views added to it in certain cases.

What it needs to do is resize the height correctly according to the amount of views that get added to the cell.

What I've done is the following
[image]
The `UIImage` and `UILabel` have a `bottom constraint` which is set to the `top` of the `UIView`

The `UIView` has a `height constraint` which is `equal to or greater then 0`. So when no views get added to the cell it needs to be 0. when there are cells being added to the cell it needs to size properly.

The code for my cell looks like this

```
struct MenuTableCellContents {
    var identifier: cellIdentifier
    var cellImage: UIImage
    var cellText: String
    //var cellFont: UIFont
    var cellTextColor: UIColor
    var subCells: [MenuTableCellContents]?

    /// Normal cells without subcells
    init(identifier: cellIdentifier, cellImage: UIImage, cellText: String, /*cellFont: UIFont,*/ cellTextColor: UIColor) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.cellImage = cellImage
        self.cellText = cellText
        self.cellTextColor = cellTextColor
        //self.cellFont = cellFont
    }

    /// Cells with subcells
    init(identifier: cellIdentifier, cellImage: UIImage, cellText: String, /*cellFont: UIFont,*/ cellTextColor: UIColor, subCells: [MenuTableCellContents]) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.cellImage = cellImage
        self.cellText = cellText
        self.cellTextColor = cellTextColor
        //self.cellFont = cellFont
        self.subCells = subCells
    }

    enum cellIdentifier {
        case standard
        case noIcon
        case subcell
    }
}

class MenuTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var cell_icon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var cell_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cell_contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var cell_contentView_height: NSLayoutConstraint!


    var cellImage: UIImage?
    var cellText: String?
    var cellTextColor: UIColor?
    //var cellFont: UIFont?

    var subCells: [MenuTableCellContents]?

    private var contentViewHeight: CGFloat?

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawSubCells()
        cell_label.text = cell_label.text?.uppercased()

        super.draw(rect)
    }

    /// draw the subcells when needed
    func drawSubCells() {
        // Check if there are subcells
        if let cells = subCells {
            let count = CGFloat(cells.count)

            // Set the height for the subcells
            contentViewHeight = 40 * count
            let contentViewFrame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width, y: self.cell_contentView.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.width, height: contentViewHeight!)
            cell_contentView?.frame = contentViewFrame

            var i = 0
            for cell in cells {

                // create a view for each cell
                let cellView = UIView()
                let cellFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i * 40), width: contentViewFrame.width, height: 40)
                cellView.frame = cellFrame

                // add a image view to each cell
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: cell.cellImage)
                let imageViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (cellFrame.height - cellFrame.height / 2) / 2, width: cellFrame.width * 0.2, height: cellFrame.height / 2)
                imageView.frame = imageViewFrame
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                // add a button to each cell
                let cellLabel = UILabel()
                let cellLabelFrame = CGRect(x: imageViewFrame.width, y: 0, width: cellFrame.width - imageViewFrame.width, height: 40)
                cellLabel.frame = cellLabelFrame
                //cellLabel.font = cell.cellFont

                cellLabel.text = cell.cellText.uppercased()
                cellLabel.textColor = cell.cellTextColor
                cellLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 15


                // add the imageview and button to the subcell view
                cellView.addSubview(imageView)
                cellView.addSubview(cellLabel)

                // add the subcell to the cell
                cell_contentView?.addSubview(cellView)
                i += 1
            }

            setupConstraints(height: contentViewHeight!)
        }
    }

    /// Set the height constraint for the cell content view in which the subcells reside
    func setupConstraints(height: CGFloat) {
        cell_contentView.frame.size.height = height
    }
}
```

then my table methods look as follows

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var menu_table: MenuTableView!

    var cellContent: [MenuTableCellContents] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCells()


        let menuCell = UINib(nibName: "MenuTableCell", bundle: nil)
        menu_table.register(menuCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "menuCell")

        menu_table.delegate = self
        menu_table.dataSource = self
        menu_table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        menu_table.estimatedRowHeight = 50

        self.revealViewController().frontViewShadowRadius = 0
        self.revealViewController().frontViewShadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    }

    /// setup the required cells for the menu
    func setupCells() {
        let normal1 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .standard, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "normal1", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)
        let normal2 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .standard, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "normal2", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)
        let normal3 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .standard, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "normal3", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)

        let sub1 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .subcell, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "sub1", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)
        let sub2 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .subcell, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "sub2", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)
        let sub3 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .subcell, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "sub3", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)
        let subs = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .standard, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "subs", cellTextColor: UIColor.black, subCells: [sub1, sub2, sub3])


        let normal4 = MenuTableCellContents(identifier: .standard, cellImage: UIImage(named: "icn_pin")!, cellText: "normal4", cellTextColor: UIColor.black)


        cellContent = [normal1, normal2, normal3, subs, normal4]
    }
}

/// required methods for the uitableview
extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellContent.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let content = cellContent[indexPath.item]

        let cell = menu_table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableCell

        cell.cell_icon.image = content.cellImage
        cell.cell_label.text = content.cellText
        cell.cell_label.textColor = content.cellTextColor
        //cell.cell_label.font = content.cellFont

        if let subCells = content.subCells {
            cell.subCells = subCells
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

does someone know where I'm going wrong?
It won't size correctly when the views are being added. The height will remain zero.

**UPDATE**

I've uploaded a test project with the issue to GitHub.
https://github.com/MaikoHermans/tableCellDynamicHeightProblem

**UPDATE 2**

For anyone facing the same problem I've updated the GitHub project mentioned in Update 1 to the working solution.

Comment: Your label grow? or his height is fixed?, if is fixed you can calculate your cell height as 40 * number of subViews + label heigth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must declare a custom class for your `UIView` that contains your inner cells, and define the intrinsic size property something like this

```
class CustomAutoresizableView: UIView {

    var subCells : [MenuTableCellContents
] = []{
        didSet
        {
            ///Your code for add cells
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
    {
        get
        {
            return CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: CGFloat(self.arrayOfValues.count * 40))
        }
    }

}
```

then you must provide the correct constraints to your main cell, and set high values of content compression resistance in vertical, I use 1000, and after that you must add this two lines in your `MenuViewController` `viewDidLoad`

```
    self.menu_table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.menu_table.estimatedRowHeight = 40
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you need replace this

```
 if let subCells = content.subCells {
        cell.subCells = subCells
    }
```

by this

```
 cell.yourCustomAutoresizableViewProperty.subCells = content.subCells
```

> EDIT

---

replace

```
 var subCells: [MenuTableCellContents] = [] {             
    willSet {
         addSubCells()
         self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
     }
```

With this

```
var subCells: [MenuTableCellContents] = [] {
    didSet{
        addSubCells()
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

You also need this method be executed before add new cells, because you can add many cells one over another

```
func cleanSubViews()
{
    for view in self.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you, if you have any problem with this please let me know

Comment: I feel like we are nearly there. One issue remains right now.  When I put it in the `willSet` or `didSet` the views will redraw because of how the table view works. You can see it does this.

Comment: Looks like it will only do that in the simulator. However when I run it on my phone it will not draw it until the cell has been outside of the view. I'll upload a test project to GitHub so you can see what I mean

Comment: Updated my post with a GitHub link

Comment: @NoSixties Ok, I will review your proyect and see what is wrong

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is that we need put the code inside of `didSet`instead of `willSet` I will update my answer, because when willSet executes you don´t have any object in your array, cells can´t be added

Comment: Did the `didSet` fix it for you? is that all you changed? I tried doing it with the `didSet` but it still caused problems for me. Believe it would redraw the same thing multiple times. where you could see the subviews getting bigger/thicker.

nvm see you clean the views.

Comment: @NoSixties yes I clean the view in your `addSubCells` method before add newCells

Comment: That did it. I have to say I was so close myself. I even wrote the `cleanSubViews` method a few hours ago. But I made 1 mistake. I didn't call it before setting `subCells` I did it afterwards... Stupid mistake.

Anyway huge thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141447/discussion-between-nosixties-and-reinier-melian).

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not provided enough information but still I will give it a shot for a vote.

Firstly, You set cell's label line 0 and property "word wrap".
Secondly, try with this (**Run and check if it's done**, If not then follow below options as well).

Next,
Use function

```
label.intrinsicContentSize().height
```

to get the height of your text in the label then set the height of it and calculate cell's height by adding other spaces.

return your new cell height in below function

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Hope this may get you your output.

Thanks.

Comment: what information are you missing?

the label doesn't need to resize. The UIView needs to resize (the black view in the screenshots).